# Refreshing a messages view in the web portal after receiving a message from the api

Tags: api, basecamp

My App uses discussion threads and comments from the api to allow project users to communicate with clients outside of the web portal. When two users are conversing and they are both in the web portal, the discussion autoupdates with a fun yellow fade when a comment is received.  But when a discussion receives a comment from the API, the project user in the web portal must hit refresh.  Is there anyway to make the portal refresh?